# Sql filtering when table is not joined

Tags: mysql

I need to filter the results of a query based on the presence of a value in a table that is not joined into the query.

I have a login form that allows users to see products only visible to them. My data model is a prod_user table that maps products to users as:

```
id  product  user
1   1        1
2   1        3
3   1        5
4   2        1
5   2        2
6   3        2
```

Each product also has other products associated with it. My prod_assoc table reads as:

```
id  product assoc
1   5       1
2   5       2
3   5       3
4   6       1
5   6       2
```

I also have a products table with the info for the product.

It's straightforward to query for the products that user can see, and then to iterate across the results and query for each product's associated products, but - how do I filter the associated products to return only the associated products assigned to that user?

The full queries I'm using are long, but basically I grab the products for a user like

```
  SELECT p.*, pu.user FROM products p LEFT JOIN prod_user pu ON pu.product=p.id WHERE user = [user variable];
```

and basically I build an array of associated products for each product like

```
   SELECT p.fieldsIWant, pa.otherFields FROM prod_assoc pa LEFT JOIN products p ON p.id = pa.assoc WHERE pa.product = [that product variable as I iterate]
```

(This sends the front end all product associations to be viewed as needed.)

The issue is, the associated products aren't filtered for that user. For example, I would want to know all the associated products for product 5 that user 1 can see. I'm getting all associated products (1, 2, and 3) but actually user 1 should only see products 1 and 2. I need to filter the associated products based on the data in the prod_user table. How do I do this? I tried joining it in a variety of ways, but none worked. Is there some way to say, give me every assoc for product 5, but only the ones that are visible to this user according to the prod_user table?

**Edit: the answer here is to indeed join the table and then just filter with an additional AND statement.**

Comment: Which associated products are visible to user 1? According to ur 2 tables, there's no way to differentiate.

Comment: the prod_user table (the top one) has an entry for each user that can view a product. so, product 1 can be viewed by users 1, 3, and 5. according to that table, user 1 can see products 1 and 2 but not product 3.

Comment: So there're 3 tables (Product,Product_user, product_associate)

Comment: Yes. Actually others (images, etc) , but for this particular problem can think of it as just those.

Comment: When I query for the associated products for each product using the bottom table, I want to filter those results based on the information in the top table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query for ur example:

(All of associated products for product 5 that user 1 can see. I'm getting all associated products (1, 2, and 3) but actually user 1 should only see products 1 and 2)

```
 SELECT pu.user, pu.product, pa.product FROM prod_user pu, prod_assoc pa
 WHERE pa.assoc = pu.product AND pa.product = 5 AND pu.user = 1;
```

Use your variable in 5 and 1.